# How to add DNSSEC signed DS records in BIND?

Tags: dns, bind, named

all (my english is not good sorry.)

Let's begin...

I created my own DNS Server use BIND9.

**Installed:** *bind bind-utils bind-chroot*

my server ip is (example IP): 123.456.789.123

Everything works fine. (no cpu more 100%) but I keep got this error every day.

```
named[17203]: error (chase DS servers) resolving 'example.com/DS/IN': 123.456.789.123#53
```

I think it's mean it can not found DS records in my example.com.
I try to search about this error and some people said I have to turn dnssec off but why?
so, I try to find how to fix this error and I got some very good explaination sites here.

https://www.os3.nl/2011-2012/students/maikel_de_boer/cia/dnssec

https://www.crc.id.au/configuring-dnssec-on-el6-and-bind-9/

I follow all the instruction from the sites above and it works! for me I got **DNSSEC signed**!
and I got DNSKEY and RRSIG records.

```
zone example.com/IN/internal: loaded serial 31125225 (DNSSEC signed)
```

But I got the new problem! The new problem is.... when I use this command (sample)

```
dnssec-signzone -N INCREMENT example.com
```

It will create signed files look like this **"example.com.signed"** and **"dsset-example.com."**

In the file "dsset-example.com." have DS records for my example.com.
But when I try to use the DS records inside "dsset-example.com." (Look like this)

```
example.com.       IN DS 64621 5 1 AFF...................FF
example.com.       IN DS 64621 5 2 333EFBC.................5FC5 AG....54S
```

and insert into my "example.com.zone" file and when I try to (resign) dnssec-signzone again I got error message like this:

```
dnssec-signzone: fatal: 'example.com': found DS RRset without NS RRset
```

I don't know how to add the **DS Records** into the example.com.zone file with out dnssec-signzone error. 
I think if I can do this the error message: *error (chase DS servers) resolving 'example.com/DS/IN'* may be gone.

Do I have to create subdimain.example.com for DS records? I dont' know for sure. So, if you guys know how to fix this problem, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

my: /etc/named.conf

```
acl "trusted" {
        127.0.0.1;
        123.456.789.123;
};

options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { none; }; # I don't have IPv6
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        auth-nxdomain no;
        allow-query { localhost; any; };
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        check-names master ignore;
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run" size 5m;
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };

        category default { default_debug; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; }
        keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

view "localhost_resolver" {
        match-clients { localhost; };
        match-destinations { localhost; };
        recursion yes;
        empty-zones-enable yes;

        // all views must contain the root hints zone
        include "/etc/named.root.hints";
        include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
};

view "internal" {
        match-clients { trusted; };     # match hosts in acl "trusted" above
        recursion yes;                  # allow recursive queries
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        allow-transfer { trusted; };
        notify no;                      # disable AA notifies
        empty-zones-enable yes;

        // all views must contain the root hints zone
        include "/etc/named.root.hints";
        include "/etc/named.domains";
};

view "external" {
        match-clients { any; };
        recursion no;
        allow-transfer { none; };

        // all views must contain the root hints zone
        include "/etc/named.root.hints";
        include "/etc/named.domains";
};
```

the file /etc/named.root.hints is:

```
// all views must contain the root hints zone
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
```

my /etc/named.domains file:
(Replaced with signed file "example.com.signed")

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "example.com.signed";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

my example.com zone file (look like this):

```
$TTL    3h
$ORIGIN example.com.
@  1D                     IN SOA  ns1.example.com.    hostmaster.example.com. (
                                        2011051202      ; serial (d. adams)
                                        3H              ; refresh
                                        15M             ; retry
                                        1W              ; expiry
                                        1H )            ; minimum
@  3600                   IN NS           ns1.example.com.
; Domain Keys
default._domainkey        IN TXT         ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
                                           "p=A0GCSq................G/o+Q" )
; NS
example.com.              IN NS           ns1.example.com.
; DNS Records
example.com.              IN A            123.456.789.123
localhost                 IN A            127.0.0.1
ns1                       IN A            123.456.789.123
www                       IN A            123.456.789.123
; DNSSEC KEY FROM Kexample.com.+....key
example.com. IN DNSKEY 256 3 5 CH....................bYd+mARYse.................VCb
example.com. IN DNSKEY 257 3 5 qX....................TYPDIsfso.................cEers
```

This one should have tag dnssec but this site need reputation more than 1500 to create a new tag. :(

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, I think: you can't. You aren't supposed to.  The DS records are supposed to be given to your domain registrar, and they are the ones who are supposed to publish them.  The idea is that the DS records establish a chain of trust, from the top-most root domain servers, through your registrar, to you.  Without the chain of trust, you could be ... who knows ... some hijacker publishing a fake zone that just happens to be dnssec-signed (and thus looks "legit").